# Example of "Type parameter hides another type" warning in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I trigger Eclipse to give me the "Type parameter hides another type" warning? I'm looking for a code example.

Here's how the documentation describes it: When enabled, the compiler will issue an error or a warning if i.e. a type parameter of an inner class hides an outer type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Test<A> {
  class Inner<A> {
    // here A denotes the generic parameter of Test.Inner
    // the type A of Test is hidden
  }
  <A> void test() {
    // here it is not a class but the type parameter A of Test is also hidden
    // if I remember well, the warning shows these too
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Outer<T> {
    class Inner<T> {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Outer<T>
{
  class Inner<T>
  {

  }
}
```